# spellchek property not working on preloaded data

Tags: jquery, html

I want to do the spellcheck in all input field and textboxes in one of my html form. To do this I have used the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("input[type='text'], textarea").prop('spellcheck',true);    
});
```

The spellcheck option is working fine while filling the form. But its not doing the checking on preloaded form data until the field is not clicked at least.

Please tell me a way to work it on preloaded data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: I am not using any plugin. Using the built in _html5_ attribute **spellchek**.

Comment: Can you make a Jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from 2 things *needing* to be true (As far as my Chrome testing goes).

A) Whitespace is usually what triggers it.

B) The element has to be in focus to trigger the spellcheck

To handles this try something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("input[type='text'], textarea").each(function(){
    $(this).text( $(this).text() + " ");
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).blur();
  })
});
```

The only issue with this is you now have whitespace on the end of your inputs. To handle this I'd make sure that on submit you trim trailing whitespace.

Here is a simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seckela/MWLUn/

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done using some kind of modification of the input fields.

You can just modify each fields like append something.

Note that, you need to focus after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a click event using JavaScript's .click() method.

Example:

```
//on form reload using JS
document.getElementById('yourtexboxID').click();

//on form reload using jQuery
$('selector1,selector2,...,selectorN').click();
```

This should resolve you problem.